# How to filter dropdown choices based on the value of another dropdown in Django Admin?

Tags: django-admin

Consider we have the following models:

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    ...

class Item(model.Models):
    shop = models.ForeignKey('Shop')  # Shop where the item is stored.
    ...

class Order(models.Models):
    shop = models.ForeignKey('Shop')  # Shop where the ordered item is stored
    item = models.ForeignKey('Item')  # Ordered item
```

We are using Django Admin for the creation of orders.

On the "Create Order" page of Django admin, there are 2 dropdowns "Shop" dropdown and "Item" dropdown.

When I choose the shop in the "Shop" dropdown I want the choices in the "Item" dropdown to contain items which are available only in the chosen shop.

How can I implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to filter results based on the value of other fields in form then you can implement this with the help of **javascript** or **Ajax** call.

If you don't want write javascript or ajax code then you can use **django-autocomplete-light** package.

you create a **form** and **forward** selected value of **shop** for **item** field in the form and access in the **view** where you can set queryset for **item** form field. You can also search in item field value.

In forms.py,

```
from django import forms
from dal import autocomplete

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    item = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                queryset=Item.objects.all(),
                widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
                        url='item_autocomplete',
                        forward=['shop']
                ),
            )
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = "__all__"
```

In urls.py,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('item_autocomplete/', ItemAutocompleteView.as_view(), name='item_autocomplete'),
]
```

In views.py,

```
from dal import autocomplete
from .models import Item


class ItemAutocompleteView(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Item.objects.none()

        shop = self.forwarded.get('shop', None)
        if shop:
            qs = Item.objects.filter(shop=shop)
        else:
            qs = Item.objects.none()

        # I assume your Item model has `title` field (this is searchable column. you can search on field value )
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(title__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

In admin.py,

```
@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = OrderForm
    ...
```

forward value doc link- https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form